# Length of values (98) does not match length of index (2456)

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am working on a [Colaboratory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jupyter#Google_Colaboratory) project for sentiment analysis of [COVID-19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19) vaccines via a Twitter data set. I am getting the error as below:

```
ValueError   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-a0fa01c42fd3> in <module>()
      3 df_vax = df_vax.fillna(0)
      4 df
----> 5 df_vax['Sentiment'] = predictions

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/common.py in require_length_match(data, index)
    530     if len(data) != len(index):
    531         raise ValueError(
--> 532             "Length of values "
    533             f"({len(data)}) "
    534             "does not match length of index "

ValueError: Length of values (98) does not match length of index (2456)
[enter image description here][1]
```

How can I fix this?

```
print('Predicting labels for {:,} vaccine tweets...'.format(len(input_ids)))

model.eval()
predictions , true_labels = [], []

for batch in vax_dataloader:
  batch = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)
  b_input_ids, b_input_mask = batch

  with torch.no_grad():
      result = model(b_input_ids,
            token_type_ids=None,
            attention_mask=b_input_mask)

  logits = result[0]
  logits = logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
  label_ids = b_labels.to('cpu').numpy()

  predictions.append(logits)
  true_labels.append(label_ids)

print('Prediction completed')

prediction_set = []

for i in range(len(true_labels)):
  pred_labels_i = np.argmax(predictions[i], axis=1).flatten()
  prediction_set.append(pred_labels_i)

prediction_scores = [item for sublist in prediction_set for item in sublist]

df_vax = df_vax.fillna(0)

df_vax['Sentiment'] = predictions
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a list of 98 elements to a dataframe column containing 2456 elements.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and comment. I am quite new to programming, I understand that there is a mismatch here between index 2456 and length of values 98 however I have a dataset which contains 3110 lines/16 columns. So I didn't understand what the root cause is here and how to solve it.

Comment: The `predictions` list seems to be a list of `batch_size x logits` numpy arrays. `prediction_scores` might be what you want to use instead, since you have turned it into a single list of prediction labels.

Comment: I'm not sure where the 2456 vs 3110 lines discrepancy comes from since you don't show the code for `vax_dataloader` or any pre-processing. perhaps you're splitting your original dataset into a training and a validation dataset at some point?

Comment: Yes, I have been using two dataset as one of them is for training and one of them is for raw data set. If there is any possibility I can share all of the code.

Comment: vax_dataset= TensorDataset(input_ids, attention_masks)

batch_size = 32

vax_dataloader = DataLoader(
            vax_dataset,  
            sampler = SequentialSampler(vax_tweets),     #Sequential Sampling
            batch_size = batch_size)